# use make install to expose a script to user

Tags: makefile, sh

inside my makefile I have the following...

```
install:
   $(INSTALL) $(PWD)/run.sh $(bindir)/run
```

so when the user clones my repo and CDs into it, I want them to type `make install`

my hope is that they will then be able to call the run.sh script as `run`

does anyone have any idea how this could be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install it globally then what you need is to copy it to a system-wide binary directory (like `/usr/local/bin` f.e.), and if you don't want them to need to use the `.sh` then you need to rename it to just `run` during the copy and add a shebang to the file (`#!/bin/sh` at the top).

One thing to keep in mind is that you might need to `chmod +x $(bindir)/run`  if the file hasn't been marked as executable before.

Comment: `INSTALL` may be a macro that expands to something like `install -m 755`.